# Where can I find a minimal installation CD for Lubuntu 11.10?

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, cd-image

I would like to install Lubuntu on my Acer Aspire 1310 laptop. I have done a little bit of research and it looks like the newest version which runs on such old laptop is Lubuntu 11.10 and the only way of installing it is through minimal CD installation procedure. I have tried, and indeed versions 12.04 and 14.04 didn't work, while version 10.04 has installed successfully.

Now I would like to perform a fresh installation of Lubuntu 11.10, but I can't find the minimal CD for it. Where can I get the minimal CD ISO for Lubuntu 11.10?

Comment: 11.10 is end of life so you will not find it.

Comment: If 10.04 installed, then just upgrade to 12.04 and then 14.04 so you get on a supported version.

Comment: I don't believe there is a minimal ISO of Lubuntu, you have to get the Ubuntu minimal and follow this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall

Answer (score 2):

All flavors of Ubuntu 11.10, including Lubuntu, have been 'end-of-lifed', which means they are not supported anymore so I do not think you will be able to find a download for it, but even if you do, I strongly suggest not to install it, for it will not receive important security updates. For more version info, here is a great site: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases.

Hope this helped!